# How do we count charges in this example of a Redox reaction equation?

Tags: homework, redox, stoichiometry

My brother(younger) had a doubt regarding this chemistry book example so I let him here :

**Question :**

Balance the equation : $\ce{H+ + MnO4- + Fe^2+ -> Fe^3+ + Mn^2+}$

**Solution steps(as given by the textbook):**

*Step 1 :*  $$\ce{MnO4-  ->  Mn^2+}$$

*Step 2 :* $$\ce{MnO4-  -> Mn^2+ + 4 H2O}$$

*Step 3 :*  $$\ce{MnO4- + 8 H+  -> Mn^2+ + 4 H2O}$$

*Step 4 :* $$\ce{MnO4- + 8 H+ + 5 e- -> Mn^2+ + 4 H2O}\tag{1}$$

*Step 5 :* $$\ce{Fe^2+ -> Fe^3+ + e-}\tag{2}$$

*Step 6 :* $5\times(2) + (1)$ and thus we have the balanced equation:

$$\ce{MnO4- + 8 H+ + 5 Fe^2+ -> 5 Fe^3+ + Mn^2+ + 4 H2O}$$

**Explanation given in the textbook for** *step 4:*  we equalise the charge by adding 5 electrons on left.

**My doubt regarding step 4:** how do I know that in *step 4* that 5 electrons do actually equalize the charge in the given equation? More accurately how do I know that there is any surplus or deficit of charge in any given equation atleast in this case?

Comment: @Nij Please check out [formatting hints for chemical equations](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3046). Using plain MathJax for chemical equations is wrong since the elements should be typeset upright, not in italics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the charges in step 4, the left side adds up to 7 and the right side adds up 2. The MnO4 on the left has a -1 charge, and the 8 hydrogens add a +8 charge, adding up to a +7 charge on the left overall. The Mn on the right has a +2 charge so that is +2.

To balance out this charge, they must be equal. How can +7 be made equal to +2? By subtracting 5. In this case, adding 5 electrons creates a -5 charge that means both sides of the equation have a +2 charge.
You just need to add up the charges like this for a given equation to balance it.